# Link to external style sheet not running

Tags: php, html, css

In **base.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Base</title>
    <style>
    body {
        background: blue;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Base</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

the background of `<body>` is blue.

But if the CSS is linked, like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Base</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/exp/mysite/css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Base</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

with **CSS** in `http://localhost/exp/mysite/css/style.css`

```
body {
    background: blue;
}
```

it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: inspect the page with firebug on mozilla or with chrome inspector to see does the page have css file included.

Comment: my guess is that http://localhost/exp/mysite/css/style.css isn't correct.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Oh, really?

Comment: probably not then. ask the guys who gave you answers ;-) they obviously know something I don't.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: There are nor errors! That's why the question is asked.

Comment: again Peter; ask the guys below. I'm out of this loop. You've been left other comments, so ping them too ;-)

Comment: @PedroLobito and if it wasn't correct, then he should be getting an error about it *(file not found blah blah blah)* but says he's not. No idea whether his system's setup to catch errors or if error reporting set to catch/display. I'll leave it to ones who gave him answers.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It was just a hint...OP: can you access http://localhost/exp/mysite/css/style.css on you browser ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Yeah I know. OP's not responding to answers neither, so that is also hard to tell whether he tried them or not. If he did, he's either gone for a really good breakfast that couldn't be passed up (pancakes with whipped cream and a strawberry coulis, yummo! now that made me hungry), or didn't feel it was worth placing comments under the answers and just leaving the question the way it is and expecting a *magic* answer to suddenly. Well well well, I hate to disappoint him, but that won't happen. Sorry Peter.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm sure op's waiting for the magic answer...talking about food...it's 3pm and I only hate 2 oranges! ora di mangiare!

Comment: I always test out before I ask. The question is pretty clear. All the comments and answers didn't lead to the solution.

Comment: si @PedroLobito è ora di mangiare per io anche. *buon appetito!*

Answer (score 0):

Can you check error and write text of error for your post? To do that, open Developer Tools, reload page, and when style.css will be red, copy and paste code of Error and text of answer from the server.

I think here may be few common problems:

1. `localhost` follows to your computer/server, but web server (Apache / Nginx) doesn't know where your link (http://localhost) should follows. I mean to which directory where css file located.
2. Second common problem is permissions. For example directory with your CSS or css file has not readable permissions.
3. There can be few more problems, like CSP or something more complicated, but i need more information from you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a relative filepath, this will also make the transfer to a production server easier:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/exp/mysite/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

(of course it depends where your html or php document is placed in the file system – if that's in a folder, it will be something like `href="../css/style.css"`

Answer (score 0):

You should link the css this way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

or link the css file the exact folder name

Answer (score 0):

Set your folder is:

```
mysite/index.html
mysite/css/style.css
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Base</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Base</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was

```
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
```

in the `.htaccess` file.